# How can a user defend themself if they were victim of Arpspoof?

Tags: windows, networking, router, security, lan

Question background:

I was testing my internal home network using arpspoof. The result was I got positive and I was able to listen to HTTP traffic using tools like sslstrip.

The Arpspoof command which I performed:

> arpspoof -i eth0 -t 10.100.4.193 10.100.1.1

Where 4.93 was a **target IP address** which was the local network and 1.1 was **the gateway**.

How I detected that the target was compromised:

- I did `traceroute` of my router gateway (10.100.1.1) from the target machine and found my arpspoofed address.

[image]

- The Internet was a little slow since it goes through the attacker's machine

Note: The first tracert was the default route, and the second one is after I perform arpspoof.

Operating system information:

Attacker: kali 2.0 sana

Victim:  Windows 7

Question:

What can I do or what do I need to do once I feel that I am a victim of Arpspoof?

Comment: I'm not an expert but [it seems](http://su2.info/doc/arpspoof.php) it works making your computer to believe that the Gw of your network is not the real one. (Read  more about [Man in the middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)). Fix somehow the Gw of your network with the real one. (Somehow because it depends from your hardware and operative system).

Comment: There are many types of MITM attacks at differant layers of the OSI. ARP attacks are notable because they operate at layer 2, with the goal of disrupting higher layer communications circuits. Most of the techniques in the wiki article are layer3 and above, but are generally more dangerous, because layer2 attacks can only affect a single LAN.

Comment: While Frank Thomas' answer is good, it should be pointed out most of the protections can only be done in an enterprise environment, and not in the home. Home routers support pretty much none of the functionality required without firmware modifications, and there's little you can do without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ARP traffic does not cross routers, ARP-based attacks only work once the attacker has control of a system within your LAN, your first lines of defense should focus on keeping them out, both digitally and physically.

In order to perform the most [damaging ARP based attacks](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/authentication_and_encryption/Understanding-Man-in-the-Middle-Attacks-ARP-Part1.html), the attacker must install a device on the network to recieve the traffic that the spoofer wants. Otherwise they are limited to DOS of internal services (just by messing with message delivery), and [sniffing oportunities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_flooding) created by attacking switch ARP tables (called mac/arp flooding, or cache poisioning). Consider isolating any wifi networks, using [VLANs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN), or other structures that break up the network at layer 2.

One common and foolproof solution is [static arp tables](http://www.arppoisoning.com/best-practices-for-defending-against-arp-poisoning-2/), if your equipment supports them them, but they are quite painful to manage, in that they must be reconfigured with every change in your network topology.

Another more feasible, but less applicable solution is [DHCP Snooping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCP_snooping), which allows DHCP-driven networks to ignore ARP updates that do not match info in the network DHCP server. this feature is supported on [Cisco devices](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst6500/ios/12-2SX/configuration/guide/book/dynarp.html) under the name `Dynamic ARP Inspection`.

The Linux utility [ARPWatch](http://linux.die.net/man/8/arpwatch) can monitor ARP changes to IP/MAC pairings, and report them. This can then be extended to [automated response if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331309/shellscript-to-monitor-a-log-file-if-keyword-triggers-then-execute-a-command), like system shutdown, the blocking of affected IPs in IPTables, etc.

Advanced switching infrastructures allow several configurations that help defeating spoofing, including the limiting of the number of MAC addresses per interface (1 to be precise), and the ability to digitally encrypt and sign network traffic between critical systems using [IPSEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec) with [certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) for identity.